# Rails 4 Secondary ID For Users With STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, userid

In a Rails 4 App users can be of 2 different types, **regular** or **premium**, stored with PostgreSQL, using **Single Table Inheritance** because they have very similar attributes.

When a user (regular) signs up to premium, I would like to be able to keep track of his "**:premium_user_id**" which would basically be a second **:id** column in the user table:

- If user with :id 25 is the first user to sign up to premium, his :premium_user_id is 1
- If user with :id 57 is the second user to sign up to premium, his :premium_user_id is 2

and so on.

I could add a **:premium_user_id** column in the User table with an index, and in the premium sign up action call increment that id like so:

```
current_user.update_attribute :premium_user_id, User.maximum("premium_user_id") + 1
```

I am not so sure about the fact that this solution needs a DB call each time, but I can't think of a place to store that Max Premium Id to avoid the db call.

Any idea for a better way to implement this?

In particular by implementing this on the Database Level through migrations and SQL statements.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add migration

```
def up
  add_column :users, :premium_user_id, :integer
  execute <<-SQL
    CREATE SEQUENCE premium_user_id_seq START 1;
    ALTER SEQUENCE premium_user_id_seq OWNED BY users.premium_user_id;
    ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN premium_user_id SET DEFAULT nextval('premium_user_id_seq');
  SQL
end


def down
  remove_column :users, :premium_user_id
  execute <<-SQL
    DROP SEQUENCE premium_user_id_seq;
  SQL
end
```

Add callback

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit do
    unless read_attribute(:type) == 'premium'
      update_column :premium_user_id, nil
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am going to read SQL docs to fully understand it. Just a question though, is there a part in what you wrote that triggers the increment so the increment works when a user signs up to Premium?

Comment: I was added callback example